# force $_POST to list all fields, even if the field contains no data/value

Tags: php

I have a multiselect drop-down field called "holds".

When nothing is selected, the holds name does not show up in $_POST

The only fields that display in the $_POST array are fields that are selected or have data in the text field.

How do I force $_POST to list all input fields (whether they contain data or not)?

Comment: If you set the default value to a space, it should send the data, and when you `trim()` it, it would show as empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the browser doesn't send the value to the server, `$_POST` won't contain it. Period.

Comment: On that note, passing an empty `$_POST` variable really isn't that different from not having that `$_POST` variable at all (especially considering type-juggling and all).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the POST, it is with the original form field. If the browser does not have some value (even if that value is blank), then it will not submit the input with the request. There is nothing which can be done about this on the server end.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a waste of space, but you might be able to send the post with an additional field which is a serialized array of the post fields (with or without data).

-Just a thought